# How to install a project for which CMake contains catkin/ROS in find_package?

Tags: ubuntu, package, ros, catkin

I have a project that begins like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(quanergy_client_ros)

    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

    ## Find catkin macros and libraries
    find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
      roscpp
      sensor_msgs
      pcl_ros
    )
```

I tried installing everything related to ros (`sudo apt install -y ros*`), I tried building some of the things like `roscpp`, then `pcl_ros` but these projects keep depending on other projects, so I don't know what to do.

As I understand, `catkin` is somethig that can build ROS projects. However, I couldn't find a way to install those dependencies.

Comment: Try rosdep: http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Ubuntu, you could install ros with all its dependencies using:

```
sudo apt-get install python-rosdep
```

in other plattform:

```
sudo pip install -U rosdep
```

for both not forget to initialize this:

```
sudo rosdep init
```

Please also check the [rosdep manual](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep) for further information